# Proof that $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}$ has at least $999$ zeros after the decimal point

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I want to show that the number $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}$ has at least $999$ zeros after the decimal point.

It seems that for $(6+\sqrt{37})^n$ that we have $n$ times $0$ for odd $n$ and $n$ times $9$ for even $n$ after the decimal point. This is what I found out by trying, but even after some thinking I can't think of a way to prove this.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}+(6-\sqrt{37})^{999}$ is an integer, and $0<\sqrt{37}-6=\frac 1{\sqrt{37} + 6}<\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: The five upvotes on this make me feel stupid. I've been thinking about it for ten minutes but I don't see what you're saying.

Comment: I've definitely not given a fully-fleshed out answer. It was meant as a little more than a hint. Is there a piece of what I've written above that is confusing, or just confusing how to apply it?

Comment: I just don't see how to apply it. Maybe for the sake of the OP it would be best to wait a couple of days before expanding further, in case they only want a hint.

Comment: Hint: The second part proves that $(6-\sqrt {37})^{999}$ is very tiny and negative.

Comment: I confirmed that $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}+(6-\sqrt{37})^{999}$ is an integer by applying the Binomial Theorem. The second part of your answer is also clear. We can conclude that $(6-\sqrt {37})^{999}$ is the part of $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}$ that comes behind the decimal point. Left to show is that $(6-\sqrt {37})^{999}$ starts with $999$ zeros. This means $|(6-\sqrt {37})^{999}| < 10^{-1000}$. That's where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: Note that $6-\sqrt{37}$ is negative, @Amarus, so $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}= N + (\sqrt{37}-6)^{999}$, where $N$ is an integer.

Comment: I know that it's negative. Indeed, I should have said that $(\sqrt{37}-6)^{999}$ is the part after the decimal point of $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}$. Still, I don't see how your last statement adds anything to the original one that $(6+\sqrt{37})^{999}+(6-\sqrt{37})^{999}$ is an integer.

Comment: So, if you add to a positive integer a number less than $10^{-1000}$ how many zeros will you get after the decimal point in the resulting sum?

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other. If I can show that $|(6-\sqrt {37})^{999}| < 10^{-1000}$, I'm done. My problem right now is that I don't see how to show that.

Comment: Which is why I wrote: $$0<\sqrt{37}-6 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{37}+6}<\frac{1}{12}$$ as the second part of the answer. Can you show that $12^{-999}<10^{-1000}$?

Comment: Okay, I didn't see the significance of the second part of your answer. Of course we have $\frac{1}{12}<\frac{1}{10}$, so $12^{-999}<10^{-999}<10^{-1000}$.

Comment: Well $10^{-999}$ is not less than $10^{-1000}$. But $12^{-999}<10^{-1000}$.

Comment: Of course not, my bad. The first power such that $12^{-p}<10^{-(p+1)}$ seems to be $p=13$. Still thinking about a compelling reason for $12^{-999}<10^{-1000}$ though...

Comment: You can write $12^{999} = (10+2)^{999} > 10^{999} + 999\cdot 2\cdot 10^{998}$ and $999\cdot 2>10^2$, so $12^{999}>10^{1000}$ and then invert.

Comment: Oh, I tried factorisations, but not decomposition into summands... Thanks!